# Setting my iPhone project to build for Release and not Debug

Tags: iphone, xcode4, release, ios-provisioning

I have an older project that I need to do an update for. However, since the realease of Xcode 4 a few things have changed. I have found where the projects app.sym file is but the folder only specify Debug. Where do I set my project to build the app and create a release folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XCode4, the configuration option has moved to scheme. you can edit scheme settings in **Product>Edit Scheme** or **Command Shift <**. In it you will need to select particular action`(Build, Run etc.)` and change the configuration under `info` tab. Change `Debug` the build configuration to `Release` for Run action.

Now, build and run your project it will create directory for release.

Answer (score 1):

Open your project, click on its scheme and choose New Scheme. After you've created this new scheme, click on Edit Scheme; select the new scheme and its destination and set Build Configuration to Release for Run and for every other that you need...
Hope this can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good tutorial for making the build for distributing,http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-create-distribution-build-with.html